# Redirect in nextJS 13 (Middleware)

Tags: next.js, middleware

I am working on my middleware, and I want to redirect the user once they logged in. Issue is that the api is not hitting the end point and is stuck in the middleware section (as per my observation) and the page is not redirecting too.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(req) {
  const url = req.url;

  if (url.includes("login")) {
    return NextResponse.redirect("localhost:3000/home", req.url);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/api/login"],
};
```

Answer (score 7):

So `NextResponse.redirect()` does not take a string as its second parameter.

I think you are looking for something more like this:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', req.url));
```

This would construct a new URL object, and that would create the url https://localhost:3000/home.

**NextResponse.redirect()**:

> Produce a response that redirects to a URL.
> The URL can be created and modified before being used in the
> `NextResponse.redirect()` method. For example, you can use the
> `request.nextUrl` property to get the current URL, and then modify it
> to redirect to a different URL.

from [Next.js Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#redirect).

**The URL:**

> The URL interface is used to parse, construct, normalize, and encode
> URLs. It works by providing properties which allow you to easily read
> and modify the components of a URL.

```js
const url = new URL("../cats", "http://www.example.com/dogs");
console.log(url.hostname); // "www.example.com"
console.log(url.pathname); // "/cats"
```

from [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).